# Any tips or principles for applying gradient to thin shapes and fonts?

Tags: website-design, gradient

I'm trying to use linear gradients on a set of thin and small shapes (and fonts). But I can't figure out how to do it so it could be seen clearly as much as possible.

Should there by any limits for the number of colors? Does the angle matter?

I found this arrow used on a website:

[image]

It looks very thin but you can definitely see the gradient. I hope my eyes are not getting this wrong but to me it looks like a combination of blue and purple. or at least some parts are brighter. I tried to zoom in all the way to see the pixel but I all see is blue

I'm also interested applying gradients to some very thin fonts like [Signale](https://dribbble.com/shots/1863593-Signale-Free-Font)

[image]

Note that there will be only few characters used, and at small size (below 80pixels)

Comment: Have you tried rasterizing layer and then adding gradient?

Comment: Copy&paste the blue arrow to Photoshop and then zoom in - you'll see that color is almost the same, the lower line is just a little bit darker. Btw, at a normal scale I also have the illusion, that the very top of the arrow has more of cyan color, but I guess it's kinda trick of the eye

Comment: @AksanaZinchanka Exactly. Its very confusing how that one was created. As you said there must be some kind of tricks and I am sure the designer developed it that way. In my eyes, at normal scale, the lower line is darker and the top one is brighter but when you zoom in it's vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Well, the observation of the gradient will definitely be affected by the colors you choose and the size of the font.

[image]

As you can see in my image, the first letter is full blue while the other two have a two color gradient in them. The level of observation will be determined by the contrast in your choice of colors.

Also, for a font as thin as this one you probably shouldn't use more than two colors and the linear gradient will be noticed better than a radial one.